# Load folder thumbnail like in Gallery

Tags: android, directory, gallery, thumbnails, android-custom-view

Currently I'm making Custom Gallery.

I don't know how to load `Folder Thumbnail` like in Gallery.

Like below image.

People who know,

Please tell me know,

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Show what have you tried yet. If you are using any adapter or something to put images in one directory then take first item from adapter and set that bitmap as background of your directory.

Comment: @Apurva I not yet tried. I don't know how to do. So I ask. "put images in one directory then take first item from adapter and set that bitmap as background of your directory" Looks like your way is the way I need to do what I want. Thank you.